# QML: How to reset item property to defaut

Tags: qml

Is there any way to reset the property of item?

For example:

```
Item{
 id: test
 x: 10; y: 10
}
```

Then i set the `x,y` to `(100,100)`.
Without change the `x,y` to `(10,10)` back.
Any function like this `test.reset()`.

My problem is:
i drag an item, if it not drop in the correct area, i wanna the item return back automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, setting a property to `undefined` causes it to be reset. An example of this is `Item`'s [`anchors`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#anchors-prop) grouped properties:

> To clear an anchor value, set it to undefined.

Qt's [property system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#requirements-for-declaring-properties) has the concept of a resettable property:

> A RESET function is optional. It is for setting the property back to its context specific default value. e.g., QWidget::cursor has the typical READ and WRITE functions, QWidget::cursor() and QWidget::setCursor(), and it also has a RESET function, QWidget::unsetCursor(), since no call to QWidget::setCursor() can mean reset to the context specific cursor. The RESET function must return void and take no parameters.

However, for your specific problem, you probably want to take a look at the [Drag and Drop example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-draganddrop-example.html). That demonstrates how to return an item to its original position.

Answer (score 1):

```
Item {
    id: test
    x: 10
    y: 10

    function reset() {
        x = 10;
        y = 10;
    }
}
```

What else?

Comment: code duplication isn't a best practice.
I'd better look at States and Transitions

Comment: @ArtemZaytsev I recognize that I thought to `States` when I wrote my answer. I edited the code before posting the answer. I also hesitated to write what you said in my answer and dealing with constants for initial values of `x` and `y` too. But I thought it was too much complicated for @user3308570. His question does not show lots of QML skills from @user3308570 so I provided him a basic answer.